# Clarification on using autowire annotation in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am new to spring and i have been reading spring online reference as well. 
I have a question regarding using autowire annotation, basically i have a web application that has for example `UserController.java`, `UserManagerService.java` and `UserDao.java`.
Please find pseudocode below:

```
 @Controller
   public class UserController
    {
    @autowire UserManagerService userManagerService;

    public String validateUser(String userpswrd,String username){
           return userManagerService.validateUser(userpswrd,username);
    }

    }
```

And the UserManagerServiceImpl:

```
 @Service
public class UserManagerServiceImpl{

@autowire UserDao userDao;

public String validateUser(String userpswrd,String username){
           return userDao.validateUser(userpswrd,username);
    }
```

I know i need to put the the following in my applicationContext.xml in order to work:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.*" />
<!-- This tells Spring to activate annotation-driven transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

My question is do i need to define the UserDao and  UserManagerService  in the applicationContext.xml file as a bean in order for the autowire annotation `UserManagerService` and  `UserDao` to work ?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No... the component scanning will detect all `@Component` related beans (including `@Service, @Repository, @Controller etc.). So no you don't need to explicitly define the beans, as that would defy the need for component-scanning and automatic wiring.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response so it is only when annotation is not used then bean is defined in xml.

Comment: No. When you don't use component-scanning. There are several other means of autowiring which don't rely on annotations.

Comment: Hi what other mean of autowiring which don't rely on annotation is there?is there an online resource you can refer which i can read to know more about it please?

Comment: The [Spring Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) reference guide is your first resource to read. You can use autowiring by name or by type (if you have setters).